Android 14: Home button should bring up Google Assistant, not "Circle to search" (changed via update)
I would like to reverse a behaviour on Android 14 that was introduced with the September update.

Previously (this is what i would like to see): Long-press of the home button brings up Google Assistant (eg. for Calling, setting alarms, etc.)
Behaviour since the update: Long-press of the home button brings up some google overlay feature to "circle to search". Bringing up the assistant now moved to some obscure swipe gesture from the corner in.

I have looked in the settings on how to define behaviour of the home button but not found anything. Ideally there would be sth like a mapping table.
On here, the closest thing I found to this usecase is a ticket that deals with switching off both functionalities (assistant and the circling feature: How to stop disabled Google Assistant popping up on home button long presses?
Any nifty way where I can directly define the behaviour of the homebutton and set it to the assistant? Alternatively any other way, eg a launcher?

Android version: 14, September Update
Phone: Samsung A55 5G

Thanks all!

According to the linked question, there should be a separate option to turn off Circle to Search under Navigation bar. Have you tried that? Or instead, it disables the whole Google Assistant?

Hi - yes, unfortunately it just disables the "Circle" feature such that the home button does not have an action assigned to it.
The assistant remains mapped to the "swipe corner" gesture

That's unfortunately not possible right now, the OS doesn't have that setting.
